# Route component needs key to properly work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a `<Route path='/user/:id' exact component={UserProfile} />` which works greatly from every url, but it doesn't if I'm already on '/user/'.

Let's say you're on /user/2 and the link goes to /user/3, the url in the browser changes but still no re-render, if I refresh the page the correct one loads.

Now after losing my sanity I've tried this:

```
<Route path='/users/:id' key={Date.now()} exact component={UserProfile} />
```

By giving it a key "magically" works from any url.

Could anyone please explain this to me?

Comment: Is this `Route` rendered as part of an array? If so, [this is why it needs a key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

Comment: I assume you have an api-call (fetch) in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method of your `UserProfile` component?

Comment: I do have a fetch on component did mount yes, on the show all users page I have a user card with `<Link to='user/:id'>` on it, and UserProfile has a fetch to my backend to grab the single user. `fetch(.../users/${this.props.match.params.id})`.

Answer (score 0):

Error is `exact` since, `id` will get change for each new user,
`<Route path='/users/:id'  component={UserProfile} />`